# Loading a jar a specific class from a specified folder?

Tags: java, jar, applet, java-io

Basically I have a JFrame what needs to load an Applet. The applet needs to be a specific class in the Jar file, I have the following code:

```
public Applet load() throws Exception {
    URL[] urls = new URL[] {new URL("file:"+getDirectory()+"file.jar")};
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    Class client = classLoader.loadClass("client");
    return (Applet) client.newInstance();
}
```

getDirectory:

```
 public static String getDirectory(){
    String dir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    return dir + File.separator + "Directory" + File.seperator;
}
```

But when the applet loads, it does nothing.

I also tried:

```
 public Applet get() throws Exception {
    Applet game = load();
    game.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    game.setBackground(Color.black);
    game.setStub(this);
    game.init();
    game.start();
    return game;
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Change `URL[] urls = new URL[] {new URL("file:"+getDirectory()+"file.jar")};` to.. `File f = new File(getDirectory()+"file.jar"); System.out.println(f.exists()); URL[] urls = new URL[] {f.toURI().toURL()};`

Comment: Note 1) that only a fully-trusted applet 2) `user.home` always points to a location on the machine *running* the applet.  I doubt your users will have the `file.jar` installed in *their* `user.home` so it will inevitably fail. --  And asking *"Does anyone know?"* after only one hour seems ambitious, given you've failed to respond to my comment within 12 hours.